From a mn vector to a n x mn matrix with diagonal structure containing vector elements
Let denote with $\mathbf{v}$ a $mn \times 1$ column vector. I aim to create a $n \times mn$ matrix with a block-diagonal structure containing elements of $\mathbf{v}$. I may manage to achieve my goal by the following expression:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{M} &=& (\mathbf{I}_{n} \otimes \mathbf{1}'_{m}) \circ (\mathbf{1}_{n} \mathbf{v}') \\
&=& \left[ \begin{array}[ccccc] 
&v_{1} & v_{2} & v_{3} & \cdots & v_{m} \\
 & &  &   &  & v_{m+1} & v_{m+2} & \cdots & v_{2m}\\  
&&&&&&&&&\ddots\\
&&&&&&&&&& v_{mn-m} & \cdots & v_{mn-1}  & v_{mn}
\end{array}\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\mathbf{I}_{n}$ is the $n \times n$ diagonal matrix; $\mathbf{1}_{m}$ and $\mathbf{1}_{n}$ are column vectors of ones of length $m$ and $n$, respectively.
However, I wonder if there is any way to get the same outcome in a simpler manner, e.g. skipping the Hadamard product to mask the off-diagonal elements. Thanks.
ps: For those programming in R, here a snippet reproducing the example above:
m <- 4
n <- 3
ones.m <- matrix(1,m,1)
ones.n <- matrix(1,n,1)
v <- matrix(runif(m*n), ncol=1)
M <- kronecker(diag(n), t(ones.m)) * (ones.n %*% t(v))

